# Draw GDI+ graphics objects using multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdi+

I have an application in which i am drawing thousands of rectangles of different size. Now here i am giving on user selection of those rectangle i am just drawing rotating border on that particular rectangle...(marching ant animation on rectangle selection).

Now if user selects few rectangles than it won't create such trouble but once user selects all or many at a time then redrawing showing flickering effect which doesn't look good and not even acceptable.

i want make it parallelization of it so i can gain the performance out of it.

Comment: Are you drawing on a memory DC?

Comment: I am getting hwnd handle for that windows and getting hDC from that handle.

Comment: I'm not sure if GDI+ likes multithreading... overlapping calls will fail with Status::ObjectBusy. hDC & Graphics per thread might be the best way. But again, flicker can be solved by double buffering...

Comment: nothing like bitmap in my app..its just & color rectangles may be thousand..i use above function to draw a rotating dash on selected rectangles..to do so i wrote this function...it will draw all rects which is present in list so loop rotates those many times.Now to rotates dash line i am changing or incrementing those dash line offset and redraw all the things again...i'm doing this on every second with help of timer(which calls this function once/sec)so that's the reason i'm getting much flickering...if u have good way to do marching ants(rotating dash on selected rectangles)suggest it

Comment: I have done double buffering at least its showing what i want..but now the coordination system got changed due to this. so when i click on rectangles the marching ant rectangles get drawn some other location...so i tried debug its coordinates not matching with expected value....any help in this one is appreciable....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use double buffering: create a [memory DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), draw on it and then perform [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a real DC. You can find a lot of examples about this technique in the Internet.

Also you may refer to this msdn article: [Flicker-Free Displays Using an Off-Screen DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969905.aspx)

Comment: nothing like bitmap in my app..its just & color rectangles may be thousand..i use above function to draw a rotating dash on selected rectangles..to do so i wrote this function...it will draw all rects which is present in list so loop rotates those many times.Now to rotates dash line i am changing or incrementing those dash line offset and redraw all the things again...i'm doing this on every second with help of timer(which calls this function once/sec)so that's the reason i'm getting much flickering...if u have good way to do marching ants(rotating dash on selected rectangles)suggest it

Comment: For double buffering you have to create a bitmap and a memory DC and draw on it. Then update real DC using BitBlt. The code changes are not so big, try it.

Comment: Thanks fo ryou help..but i tried the case which you said...i did it in my funcion it self (which is given above)..in my paint method double buffering is already there...now i will again clarify my req..the function draws thousand of rect on every seconds why bcz i want to rotates the dash line on selected rectangle..so it draws thousands of rects all in every second..so i was thinking it to make it parallel by threading...let me know if you have any idea.